# Getting NullPointerException errors when trying to use multiple classes for the first time

Tags: java, class, oop, object, this

I am trying to get my `addStudent()` method in the `Roster` class to work here.

It's supposed to add a given student to this roster. If the student is already on the roster, or the `numStudents == stopPoint`, it doesn't change the roster and returns false. If it is successful it returns true.

Roster Class:

```
public class Roster {
    Student[] students;
    int numStudents;
    int stopPoint;
    Course course;


    //constructor for this class initialize this roster to empty
    public Roster(int stopPoint, Course course)
    {
       this.stopPoint = stopPoint;
       this.course = course; 
    }



    //returns a string that represents the object for printing
    public String toString()
    {
       String res = "";
       for(int j = 0; j < numStudents; j++)
       {
          res = res + "\n" + students[j].toString();
       }
       return course + " " + numStudents + "/" + stopPoint+res;
    }




    //returns true if and only if the number of students in it is at stopPoint
      public boolean isFull(int numStudents, int stopPoint)
      {
         if (numStudents == stopPoint)
         {
            return true;
         }
         else
            return false;   
      }



 /*add given student to this roster if student already on roster 
    or numStudents already == stopPoint, will not change roster and return 
    false but return true if successful, else false
 */
    public boolean addStudent(Student student)
    {
        if(this.numStudents < this.stopPoint)
        {
            this.students[numStudents] = student; // here is where I get the error
            this.numStudents++;
            return true;
        }
        else
           return false;

   }
}
```

Testing Class:

```
public class TestRoster 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Student s1 = new Student("John","Doe");     
        Course c1 = new Course(198, 111);            
        Roster r1 = new Roster(4, c1);              
        System.out.println(r1);
        testAdd(r1, s1);            
    }

    private static void testAdd(Roster r, Student s)
    {
        System.out.println(s.familyName+" "+r.addStudent(s));        
        System.out.println(r);                                      
    }   
}
```

Student Class:

```
public class Student 
{
    String personalName;
    String familyName;

    public Student(String pName, String fName)
    {
        personalName = pName;
        familyName = fName;
    }

    public String toString( )
    {
        return "Student: " + familyName + ", "+ personalName;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the Course Class:

```
public class Course 
{
    int deptNum;
    int courseNum;

    public Course(int deptNum, int courseNum)
    {
        this.deptNum = deptNum;
        this.courseNum = courseNum;
    }

    public String toString( )
    {
        return deptNum + ":" + courseNum;
    }


}
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at assign4.Roster.addStudent(Roster.java:56)
    at assign4.TestRoster.testAdd(TestRoster.java:17)
    at assign4.TestRoster.main(TestRoster.java:13)
Java Result: 1`
```

Comment: Please include the error stacktrace

Comment: Stacktrace would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers suggest using an arbitrary number for the array instansiation, this is not a good idea as you never know if it will be enough.

Your `Roster` class knows how many students there should be (via the constructor), you should initialize the `Student` array with `stopPoint`:

```
Student[] students;
int numStudents;
int stopPoint;
Course course;

public Roster(int stopPoint, Course course)
{
    this.stopPoint = stopPoint;
    this.course = course; 
    this.students = new Student[this.stopPoint]
}
```

Since you can't touch your class variables, you can and should initialize the array within the constructor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped me understand a couple of things.